# How to perform anova between one specific col and multiple cols?

Tags: r, dplyr, anova, across

I want to perform anova between one col and other col, and my script is like this

```
summarise(
 across(.col = where(is.numeric),
        .fn = aov(. ~ Species, data = iris   
 ))
```

And then I tried

```
list(
 across(.col = where(is.numeric),
        .fn = aov(. ~ Species, data = iris   
 ))
```

But still does not work....
Would someone kindly offer advice?
Thanks.

Comment: `summary(aov(cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data = iris))`

Comment: @KaiLi With tidyverse I believe you can also try: `iris %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% map(~ summary(aov(.x ~ iris$Species)))`